# how to call a function from another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am appending a text box on click of Add New Candidate button and I also want to call validate the function of NewCandidate component on the click of save button I have tried with the following code but it's throwing an error if anybody knows the solution please answer.........................................................................................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0-alpha1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>    
      </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>   
    <script type="text/jsx">
    class NewCandidate extends React.Component{
        validate(){
            alert()
        }       
        render(){
            return(
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="2">Candidate details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th><td><input type="text" ref="candName" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            )
        }
    }
    var CandidateList = [<NewCandidate />];

        class Interview extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super();
                this.state={candidates:props.candidates}

            }
            updateCandidateList(newCandidate){
                var updatedCandidates=this.state.candidates;
                updatedCandidates.push(newCandidate);
                this.setState({candidates: updatedCandidates})  
            }
            render(){   
                return(
                    <div>
                        <Candidate candidates={this.state.candidates} />
                        <AddNewCandidate candidateList={this.updateCandidateList.bind(this)} />                     
                    </div>              
                )
            }       
        }
        class AddNewCandidate extends React.Component{
            constructor(){
                super()             
            }
            addNewCandidate(e){
                e.preventDefault();             
                this.props.candidateList(<NewCandidate />)
            }   
            render(){
                return(
                    <form>
                        <button onClick={this.addNewCandidate.bind(this)}>Add New Candidate</button>    
                        <button type="button" onClick={NewCandidate.validate.bind(this)}>Save</button>  
                    </form>
                )
            }
        }
        class Candidate extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
            }
            render(){
                var items=this.props.candidates.map((item)=>{
                    return (<div>{item}</div>)
                });

                return(
                    <div>
                        {items}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }   
        ReactDOM.render(<Interview candidates={CandidateList}/>,document.getElementById("root"));           
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message you are getting.  Please don't just say "it's throwing an error" and expect us to figure out what the error is.

Comment: what is the purpose of validate function? Do you want  to validate single candidate or all the candidates?

Comment: I have to validate all the candidate with a single button save after validation is passed I have to save all the data but for now I need help on validation only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following working snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        class NewCandidate extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
          }

          handleChange(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.handleCandidateChange(e.target.value, this.props.indexVal);
          }

          render(){
            return(
              <div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="2">Candidate details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th><td><input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }


        class Interview extends React.Component {
          constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              candidates: [],
              values: []
            }
            this.addNewCandidate = this.addNewCandidate.bind(this);
            this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
            this.handleCandidateChange = this.handleCandidateChange.bind(this);
          }

          handleCandidateChange(value, index) {
            const newValues = [].concat(this.state.values);
            newValues[index] = value;
            this.setState({values: newValues});
          }

          handleSave(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.state.values.forEach((val, index) => {
              alert(`Validate ${index+1} value`);
            })
          }

          addNewCandidate(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const candidateList = [].concat(this.state.candidates);
            candidateList.push(<div key={`candidate-${candidateList.length}`}><NewCandidate indexVal={candidateList.length} handleCandidateChange={this.handleCandidateChange}/></div>)
            this.setState({candidates: candidateList});
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                {this.state.candidates}
                <button type="button" onClick={this.addNewCandidate}>Add New Candidate</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSave}>Save</button>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }

        // render Interview component
        ReactDOM.render(<Interview />,document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but save button is disappeared after its click and it should not be duplicated on the click add new candidate button, actually, the save button must call the validate  function of each component

Comment: Are you expecting save button beside each text field?

Comment: no, actually there should be single save button like Add new candidate button

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to see all the alerts when you click the save button, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. The main App component acts as a container for all relevant information and actions. We then use child components that are used for presenting data which will be using methods that have been passed down from the container to perform actions.

```js
class NewCandidate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: ""
  };
  handleChange = evt => this.setState({
    name: evt.target.value
  });
  addCandidate = () => {
    const { name } = this.state;
    if (name === "") {
      return console.warn("input is empty");
    }
    return this.setState({
      name: '',
    }, () => this.props.add(name));
  };
  render() {
    if (this.props.display) {
      return (
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.addCandidate}>Add Candidate</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

const Candidate = ({ candidate }) => <div>{candidate.name}</div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showNewCandidateForm: false,
    candidates: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Jeff"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Andrew"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Jess"
      }
    ]
  };
  addCandidate = name => {
    alert('validation here');
    const { candidates } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      showNewCandidateForm: false,
      candidates: [
        ...candidates,
        {
          id: candidates[candidates.length - 1].id + 1,
          name,
        }
      ]
    });
  };
  showNewCandidateForm = () => this.setState({
    showNewCandidateForm: true
  });
  hideNewCandidateForm = () => this.setState({
    showNewCandidateForm: false
  });
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NewCandidate
          display={this.state.showNewCandidateForm}
          hide={this.hideNewCandidateForm}
          add={this.addCandidate}
        />
        {this.state.candidates.map(candidate => {
          return <Candidate key={candidate.id} candidate={candidate} />;
        })}
        <button onClick={this.showNewCandidateForm}>New Candidate</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```